# Set specific SDK via cmake

Tags: cmake, sdk, visual-studio-2017, windows-10

Hi I do transfer from vs 2013 to vs 2017 with update c++

currently i use this command

```
set CMAKE_CMD=cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" %PROJECT_PATH%
```

with this command I build the VS solution and I get the default Windows SDK 10 tool set.

How I can build solution via cmake with Windows SDK tool set 8.1 ?

Comment: Have you tried CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION ?

Comment: No. As I understand I cant change the SDK dynamically only it i add full path for specific SDK in Cmake. This solution not good for me due when i run CI each time it's another path